# Visual Studio 2019 Watch Window: IntelliSense Completion

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

The **expected behavior** when pressing enter on an IntelliSense suggestion in the Watch Window would be that the selected item is filled in and that I can **continue typing**.

Instead, the selection is filled in and then immediately executed so that I have to re-select the entry field each time.

This is obviously just a minor nuisance, but it would be great if someone knew how to change this behavior (or at least provide a shortcut that only enters the suggestion without immediately executing).

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior, but normally I trigger completion with the `TAB` key

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto TAB works - thank you! And to clarify: If you press Enter in the context of the Watch Window it behaves just the same?

Comment: Well, yes, enter is for executing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agreed with Camilo and thanks for his help. To help improve this issue and help other community members handle and search similar issues, I have added an answer here:

**Answer**

**Actually**, how to invoke **Intellisense** on **Watch Window** is quite different from the Code Editor. And **Enter** key under watch window is for executing the detection of the input content. Every time you click the enter key on the watch window, it will monitor the values that have been entered.

**Suggestion**

**So** if you want to continue the pop-up suggestions for certain content on the **Watch Window**, you should use **Tab** key.